# Summarizing amount of times options are selected true/false in a concatenated string

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm pretty new to KQL and I'm having a difficult time with it (I don't have a background in stats, and I'm not very good at SQL either). I have telemetry data coming in from Microsoft AppCenter that I want to parse out into some charts but I'm trying to first figure out how to split a concatenated string that is essentially a dictionary that has two possible values: true and false. I want to count the number of each, so every key would have 2 values (true/false) which would also each have a numerical count value.

The input string I'm trying to get this data from is of the format `Remove Splash/Main Menu Branding=True;Disable Aim Assist=False` - unique items are split by ; and each pair is split by =. I am trying to figure out which options my users are using this way. The example string here would be split into:

```
Remove Splash/Main Menu Branding = True (count 1)
Disable Aim Assist = False (count 1).
```

If a new item came in that was `Remove Splash/Main Menu Branding=True;Disable Aim Assist=True` the summarized data would be

```
Remove Splash/Main Menu Branding = True (count 2)
Disable Aim Assist = False (count 1).
Disable Aim Assist = True (count 1).
```

So far I've got a query that selects a single item, but I don't know how to count this across multiple rows:

```
customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(7d)
| where name == "Installed a mod"
| extend Properties = todynamic(tostring(customDimensions.Properties))
| where isnotnull(Properties.["Alternate Options Selected"])
| extend OptionsStr = Properties.["Alternate Options Selected"] //The example string in above
| extend ModName = Properties.["Mod name"]
| where ModName startswith "SP Controller Support" //want to filter only to one mod's options
| extend optionsSplit = split(OptionsStr, ";")
| summarize any(optionsSplit)
```

I'm not sure how to make counts of it in a dictionary though. If anyone has any suggestions or tips or examples on something like this, I would really appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
let MyTable = datatable(Flags:string) [
    "Remove Splash/Main Menu Branding=True;Disable Aim Assist=False",
    "Remove Splash/Main Menu Branding=True;Disable Aim Assist=True"
];
MyTable
| extend Flags = split(Flags, ";")
| mv-expand Flag = Flags to typeof(string)
| summarize Count = count() by Flag
```

The output of this is:

```
| Flag                                  | Count |
|---------------------------------------|-------|
| Remove Splash/Main Menu Branding=True | 2     |
| Disable Aim Assist=False              | 1     |
| Disable Aim Assist=True               | 1     |
```

Explanation:

1. First you split every input string (that contains multiple flags) into substrings, so that each will only have a single flag - you achieve this by using `split`.
2. Now your new `Flags` column has a list of strings (each one containing a single flag), and you want to create a record with every string, so you use the `mv-expand` operator
3. Lastly, you want to count how many times every key=value pair appears, and you do it with `summarize count() by Flag`

In case you want to see one record (in the output) per Key, then you can use the following query instead:

```
let MyTable = datatable(Flags:string) [
    "Remove Splash/Main Menu Branding=True;Disable Aim Assist=False",
    "Remove Splash/Main Menu Branding=True;Disable Aim Assist=True"
];
MyTable
| extend Flags = split(Flags, ";")
| mv-expand Flag = Flags to typeof(string)
| parse Flag with Key "=" Value
| project Key, Value
| evaluate pivot(Value, count(Value))
```

Its output is:

```
| Key                              | False | True |
|----------------------------------|-------|------|
| Remove Splash/Main Menu Branding | 0     | 2    |
| Disable Aim Assist               | 1     | 1    |
```

You wrote that you're new to KQL, so you might find the following free Pluralsight courses interesting:

- [How to start with Microsoft Azure Data Explorer](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/microsoft-azure-data-explorer-starting)
- [Basic KQL](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/kusto-query-language-kql-from-scratch)
- [Azure Data Explorer – Advanced KQL](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/microsoft-azure-data-explorer-advanced-query-capabilities)

P.S. In the future please provide sample input in `datatable` format (if you're using Kusto Explorer, just select the relevant query results, right-click on the selection, and click `Copy as datatable() literal`), and also the expected output in a table format, so that it will be easier to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for this. Sorry about late response, been very busy :) I modified it a bit to count the number of each (before your edit), but this is exactly what I wanted, really appreciate it. I was able to do this on a few other datasets as well to also get useful info!